# How do I read telnet data and save to a new log file every day?

Tags: putty, telnet

I use to use Indigo Terminal Emulator from shadeBlue. I can't buy a license anymore, shadeBlue is not in business, and I had to migrate servers. I am using Putty to read my data and save it to a log file. I know I can put &M-&D-&Y for month-day-year in the log file. The trouble is I want a new log file every day. Indigo did exactly what I wanted, regarding creating new files every day. Using Putty, I thought I could taskkill Putty with Task Scheduler, this is a Windows server, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there something else besides Putty that has this functionality similar to Indigo? Is there still a way to license Indigo? Should I try a C# program to start and kill Putty?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: at first, product suggestions are off topic, second license question also, and your question does not fit the the common standard it requires to ask here [ask]